# Rails, product variants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested

I am building an e-commerce app the hard way(no spree, shoppe, etc) so that I can learn rails. Currently, I have a **restaurant** model, **meals** model, and **orders** model. Users(using devise) can open meals, fill in an order's form with an attribute :quantity and send the order to their carts(keeping :restaurant_id, meal_id, :qty). However, meals in restaurants normally have sizes and supplementals(with cheese, with ketchup, etc.). Ideally, I would build something like spree_flexi_variants
but I just can't see how to do this... Should I nest "characteristics" and "supplementals"(becoming 2 levels deep as **meals** is currently nested in **restaurant**) in the meals, or somehow add an attribute to the meals model? Thank you guys for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your meal object has the supplements as child items, in which case the order is also going to need child items, in this case they would be a join between supplements and order.

You don't HAVE to do it this way, it's just one possible approach. You could store the selected supplements as a serialised hash on the order row instead.

If this is a project aimed at learning, I would try both and see which feels nicest - it's all useful practice!

Comment: I will try the approach with an attribute :supplementals in the meal's model which stores all the current options + price for each option. Thanks :)